# mysql select id where column matching all values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table:

```
id  filter_id
1   5
2   5
3   5
3   17
4   17
5   17
```

ids are not unique

I need somethings like

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE filter = 5 AND filter = 17
```

but it returns nothing becuse filter column cannot be 5 and 17 at the same time

so I need get id = 3 for result.

I tried

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE filter IN (5, 17)
```

but I need AND, not OR operation

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT  id
FROM table
WHERE filter IN (5,17)
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT filter) = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select id   from table 
where filter_id IN (5, 17)
group by id  
having count(distinct filter_id) =2
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with using `sum`

```
SELECT  id
FROM table
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(filter = 5)
and SUM(filter = 17)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/418758/1)

Answer (score 0):

Without grouping data just in case if there are so many rows in the table :

```
SELECT distinct id FROM table t1 WHERE filter_id = 5 and exists (select 1 from table t2 where filter_id = 17 and t1.id = t2.id);
```